# Reverse a List in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, data-structures

Why this code for reverse a list in java doesn't work correctly?

```
import java.util.List;
public class Main{
public static List<Integer> reverseArray(List<Integer> a){
        int n = a.size();
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++){
            temp = a.get(n-1);
            a.set(n-1, a.get(i));
            a.set(i, temp);
            n--;
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you use [edit] option and explain what makes *you* think it "doesn't work correctly"? How did you use it, what results did you expect and what did you get instead?

Comment: Also note that you are checking `i < n/2;` but later doing `n--`. Does it look right?

Comment: `n-1-i` instead of `n-1`

Comment: BTW `a.set(i, a.set(n-1-i, a.get(i)));`  could be done for swapping, as `set` returns the old value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you name a method to reverse a list, “`reverseArray`”?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use such an implementation as you're being destructive to the parameter.  If you're going to return a list, then create a new list.  Anyone using such a function will assume their source list will remain unaltered, but with your implementation, that isn't true.  Do something more like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> reverse(List<T> list) {
    List<T> reverse = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse.add(list.get(i));
    }

    return reverse;
}
```